# How to create a drop-down parameter which automatically updates based on the current date in SQL Server Report Builder?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm building a report in **SQL Server Report Builder**.

I want to have:

- Drop-down parameter of month and year (i.e. "May 2018").
- Second drop-down parameter would determine if the report is month-to-date or year-to-date.

I would like the first drop-down parameter to automatically update itself as time progresses. For example, on July 1, 2018, a "June 2018" option would be added automatically.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What SQL Server version are you on? Also how far back do you want to go for your `Month Year` drop down list?

Comment: @M.Ali SQL Server 2012. SQL Report Builder 2016. Probably just January 2017 through the present.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new dataset for this drop down in your SSRS report and use the following query for your dataset:

```
SELECT FORMAT( EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH , -n , CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
              , 'MMM yyyy') [MMM_YYYY] 
FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n 
        FROM 
                (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x1(x),
                (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) x2(x) 
    ) x
WHERE n <= 24  --<-- change here to get upto last hundred months 
ORDER BY n
```

It will give you for last 24 months in your drop down list, change the where clause to get more months shown in your drop down list.

Comment: Thanks! Does this work if I have several existing charts (with queries of their own) already in the report? For instance, I have a chart and query that shows which sections of a website get the most usage. I want to limit the time period on this graph as explained above.

Comment: M.Ali - what would be an alternative to the EOMONTH Function?  How would you write the code?

Comment: @BIReportGuy You can use something like `SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,-1 , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0, @dtValue)+1 , 0 ) )`